# How to fix print code with assembleur intel 64

Tags: assembly, printing

I try to write a print code using assembleur language ,the sentence is stocked in %edi register and i want to show it in the terminal using C code  but i can't ! I don't know where is the probleme! Can someone help me please?

Code :

```
  .data


# buffer:
  #  .space 22
.bss
.lcomm buffer, 1024
.globl Myprintf
.text

Myprintf:
addl %edi, buffer
mov $buffer, %r10


do_chaine:
movb (%r10), %r8b
incb %cl
inc %r10b
cmp %r8b, fin


jz chaines
jmp do_chaine



chaines: 
movl  %ecx, %edx
movl $0, %ecx
movl (%r10), %ecx 
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx  
int $0x80
jmp done



done:
mov $1, %eax
mov $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

Comment: You are trying to use 32 bit system calls in 64 bit code.  Don't do this.  Use 64 bit system calls.  Likely, this is the whole reason your program doesn't work.

Comment: @fuz: no, it's not trying to print a stack buffer, and it wouldn't link into a PIE executable (`addl %edi, buffer` not `buffer(%rip)`, and `mov $buffer, %r10` is a 32-bit sign-extended immediate, not `movabsq`), so assuming Linux (which I think we can based on the call numbers and the), if this links at all the buffer is in the low 31 bits of virtual address space and thus `int $0x80` will work.  (But still be a bad choice.)    The code loads 4 bytes starting with the first `0` byte in `buffer `, and passes that as the pointer arg for `write(1, buf, strlen(buf)+uninitialized garbage)`

Comment: The code starts with a memory-destination add of the low 32 bits of your first arg into static storage.  Use a debugger and `strace` (except strace won't decode `int $0x80` calls correctly in 64-bit code), and include more about what happens vs. what's supposed to happen to make this a [mcve].   I can't even tell if you meant to pass an address in RDI, or if you really want to pass up to 4 ASCII bytes in EDI.  Having a buffer at all hints at wanting to pass characters in a register by value, not by pointer, but that's really weird.